What is the impact of the rollover of VIX futures contracts on VIX options?
I am inquiring about the potential impact of futures rollover on VIX options prices. I am currently exploring diagonal and calendar spreads on VIX options, and I need to modelize this. Your insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Sincerely,
Samuel

Upvoting because I am interested in the answer to this question as well.
